# Polynomial division with remainder problem

Tags: polynomials

Not sure how to solve this one: If the remainder of dividing the polynomial $x^{2018}-ax^{2017}+bx^{2015}+c$ by $x^3-x^2+x-1$ is $ax+b$, where $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$, how much is $a-b+c$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

Firstly, notice that:

\begin{align*}
x^{2018} - ax^{2017} + bx^{2015} + c = q(x)(x^{3} - x^{2} + x - 1) + ax + b
\end{align*}

Secondly, notice that:
\begin{align*}
x^{3} - x^{2} + x - 1 = x^{2}(x-1) + (x - 1) = (x^{2} + 1)(x - 1)
\end{align*}

Comment: Oh thank you, I got 3/2 as an answer, that seems right enough